# Android. Иногда устройство не пробуждается

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Имеется приложение, часть которого работает по типу будильника.

**Задача:** *в определённый момент времени, несмотря ни на что вывести устройство из спящего режима и запустить Activity.*

Алгоритм построен с использованием alarmManager.

**Так заводится будильник:**

```
                //Работа с Intent для запуска AlarmReciver
                final Intent my_intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AlarmRecever.class);

                //Устанавливаем время, на которое нужно завести (Время сейчас + 10 секунд)
                TimeAlarm = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (10 * 1000);

                //Работа с Pending Intent
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 

                //Работа с Alarm Manager
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, TimeAlarm, pendingIntent);
```

**Это код для AlarmReciver, который запускает Activity `SignalActivity`:**

```
public class AlarmRecever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Intent intentSignal = new Intent(context, SignalActivity.class);
        intentSignal.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ComponentName komponent = intentSignal.getComponent();
        Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(komponent); 
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);//Запускаем Activity "intentSignal"
    }
}
```

> Проблема возникает не всегда, но бывает в ≈10% случаев.

Проблема заключается в том, что, когда экран выключен, устройство не всегда выходит из спящего режима. То есть Activity запускается только тогда, когда пользователь разбудит смартфон (нажмёт например HomeButton).

Когда же устройство подключено к компьютеру, то такой проблемы ещё ни разу не возникало.

> В manifest'e прописал:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
> ```
>
> *Могу предположить, что проблема в том, что устройство бывает загруженным и ему не хватает ресурсов на запуск Activity. Вероятно
>   нужно как-то изменить приоритет.*

Проблему заметил на моём устройстве, Galaxy S4

Comment: Возможно устройство засыпает до того как запускается `Activity`. Попробуйте делать блокировку `WakeLock` прямо в ресивере. Ну и с API21 вообще рекомендуется использовать `JobScheduler`, но как там с запуском активностей не в курсе, если честно.

Comment: @woesss , что-то не могу нигде найти пример, как делать блокировку WakeLock прямо в ресивере. Не подскажите код?

Comment: @woesss Или вы имеете в виду это? `intentSignal.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: @woesss , благодарю. Попробую.
Если проблема возникнет снова, я сообщу.
На данный момент ваше предложение единственное и надеюсь верное.

Comment: Проблема возникла снова. :(

Comment: Обновите вопрос актуальным кодом. И укажите на каких API и аппаратах проблема появляется. Во-первых в каждом новом API кастрируют понемножку всё, что может сажать батарейку, кроме растущих как на дрожжах гуглосервисов, естественно. Во-вторых вендоры тоже проявляют подобную "заботу".

Comment: @woesss , благодарю вас, что не забиваете на вопрос. :) А в коде нечего добавлять, код не изменился. В этот промежуток времени проблему не замечал видимо потому, что не так активно пользовался приложением, а тут решил ещё раз протестировать и 2 раза не сработало. Насчёт моего устройства - добавил.